# Xamarin.iOS Error: The Apple iOS SDK is not installed. (iOS9, XCode 7 beta)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have installed XCode 7 beta, Xamarin.iOS 8.99.4 and Xamarin Studio 5.9 on Mac OSX 10.10.5.

I refer this article. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ .

If I debug/run a Xamarin.iOS app on iOS Simulator (iOS9), it works well.

But when I debug/run it on my iPhone5s device (iOS9), Xamarin shows this error message.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: The Apple iOS SDK is not installed. (ex33.iOS)
```

The "Build Output" window show following message.

```
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/username/Projects/ex33/iOS/ex33.iOS.csproj" (Build target(s)):

    Target PrepareForBuild:
        Configuration: Debug Platform: iPhone

    Target _DetectAppManifest:
        FindItemWithLogicalName Task
          Items:
            Info.plist
            Entitlements.plist
            packages.config
          LogicalName: Info.plist
          ProjectDir: /Users/username/Projects/ex33/iOS
          ResourcePrefix: Resources

    Target _DetectSdkLocations:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: error : The Apple iOS SDK is not installed.
        DetectSdkLocations Task
          TargetFrameworkIdentifier: Xamarin.iOS
          TargetArchitectures: ARMv7, ARM64
          SdkVersion: <null>
          XamarinSdkRoot: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current
          SdkRoot: <null>
          SdkDevPath: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
          SdkUsrPath: <null>
          SdkPlatform: <null>
          SdkIsSimulator: False
    Task "DetectSdkLocations" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_DetectSdkLocations" in project "/Users/username/Projects/ex33/iOS/ex33.iOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/username/Projects/ex33/iOS/ex33.iOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/username/Projects/ex33/iOS/ex33.iOS.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets (_DetectSdkLocations target) ->

    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: error : The Apple iOS SDK is not installed.

     0 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)


---------------------- Done ----------------------
```

What can I do?

P.S. When I debug/run a app in XCode 7 beta, it works on my iPhone well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the preferences in Xamarin Studio.. you may need to change the Apple SDK path to point to the Beta location.

By default, it should be looking in the default location, but that will only be present if you have the General Release (non Beta) Xcode and iOS SDK installed too.